# Python - resort list based on another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 lists:

```
a=[45, 41, 42, 43, 44]
b=[41, 42, 43, -44, -45]
```

i want to sort `b` based on `a` without the the negative sign,
so after resort it should be like :

```
a=[45, 41, 42, 43, 44]
b=[-45, 41, 42, 43, -44]
```

i tried to compare elements but i face problem in negative sign

thanks

Comment: use `abs()` to ignore the negative sign?

Comment: For example: `abs(-45)` is 45

Comment: Is `b = [-45, 41, 42, 43, -44]` your expectation output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> sorted(b, key=lambda x: a.index(abs(x)))
[-45, 41, 42, 43, -44]
```

Or if you want to sort `b` in its place

```
b.sort(key=lambda x: a.index(abs(x)))
```

Comment: awesome that what i was looking for
Thanks  :)

Answer (score 2):

Answer above is elegant and concise.

However if you are operating on larger lists you could consider using a dictionary of positions to prevent calls to index.

Complexity would remain at O(n log n) vs O(n^2 log n)

```
a=[45, 41, 42, 43, 44]
b=[41, 42, 43, -44, -45]


# populate dictionary to reduce number of array scans
keys = {}
for x in xrange(len(a)):
  keys[a[x]] = x

# key is position in a, or -1
def key(x):
  x = abs(x)
  if x in keys:
    return keys[x]
  return -1

b.sort(key = key)

print b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `abs` for absolute value.

```
>>> sorted(map(abs,b),reverse=True)
    [45, 44, 43, 42, 41]
```

Comment: This is not what he wants.

Comment: this is not what i want dear

Comment: @MostafaMohamed in your comment you asked how to do `abs()` so that's a little misleading. I just showed you how to do `abs()` dear

Comment: my question that i want to order b based on a with the negative sign :)